# Don't track file but replace when file changed in Git

Tags: git, version-control

Is it possible to do not track files in git history, but if it updated replace the old one?

I have some Java libraries that sometimes updates,  I do not want to track them in git repository, but want to store this libs with other files and when file updated upload new version to repository.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - it's tracked, or it's not.

Comment: The best solution is to use a tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) that can take care of library updates for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. If a file is in the repository, it will show in the history.